# Java, what is the purpose of Partially Initialised Object exploitation

Tags: java, security

I am doing some personal research for examinations. Past exams have asked `Outline how a partially initialised object in Java is vulnerable to exploitation`. and also, `What are the possible complications of somebody exploiting said Objects in your application`

Now, i found this resource here: [securecoding.cert](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/jg/VOID+Prevent+partially+initialized+objects+from+being+used)

On the above website, i can see examples as to how its done, but i can't seem to see or understand the purpose of it, what can you actually maliciously do with such Objects.

From what i understand, you should always check that Object instantiation has completed when performing operations (e.g. Boolean or similar) like so;

```
class BankAccount {
  private int balance; // Defaults to 0
  private volatile boolean initialized = false;

  public BankAccount() {
    if (!performAccountVerification()) {
      throw new SecurityException("Invalid Account");
    }
    balance = 1000;  
    // ...
    initialized = true;
  }

  public int getBalance() {
    if (!initialized) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Class not initialized");
    }
    return balance;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Code taken from the above resource.

You should also use volatile, as you want to ensure synchronisation because part of the problem is the fact that the Java Memory allows other Threads to access these Partially Initialised Objects.

So in summary:

- Why would you want to do this?
- What can you actually do with these Objects
- Should you always be concerned about this, or only in critical systems?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: "Java compilers are allowed to reorder the statements of the constructor so that the boolean flag initialized is set to true before the initialization has concluded. " which may show balance as ZERO though balance = 1000;

Comment: "Why would you want to do this"---> Depends on business requirements. There could be some business applications where object initialization with certain state should happen before any operation occur on that object. Is this common scenario? may not, but not uncommon scenario.

Comment: Did you see the pink message on top of the page? "This guideline has been labeled void and designated for future elimination from the Cert Oracle Secure Coding Standard for Java."

Comment: The link seems to be inoperable - host doesn't respond. Anyone with the same issue, or is it my provider?

Comment: @Dima I did see the message, but since we can still get asked about it, writing that it is being removed does not go down well in an examination unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I don't have access to a bank account, and your class isn't checking that `initialized` flag,  I could theoretically be able to do something like this:

```
class Thief extends Thread {
    public BankAccount ba = null;
    void run() {
        do { 
            if(ba != null) ba.transferAllMoneyToDima();           
        } while(ba == null);
    }
}

Thief th = new Thief();
th.start();
th.ba = new BankAccount();
```

What happens here is that `BankAccount` constructor is supposed to verify that I have access to the account, and throw an exception if not. By optimizer is allowed to reorder certain operations. In particular, it can assign the object to `th.ba` immediately after it is allocated, before the constructor completes. If that happens, my `Thief` thread will see the non-null value, and steal of the money before the vertification completes and determines that I should not have been allowed to do this.

Comment: What I wonder in cases such as this is where exactly such an attack would be applicable. The intruder would need access to the server and WAR/EAR there, modify the WAR/EAR with his own class, and deploy that. With that kind of access all kinds of less fancy attacks are possible.

Comment: Well, you are assuming that all programmers are honest people, or, at least, the ones, working at the bank are. While this assumption makes total sense to me, the guys at oracle, who wrote those guidelines, might have some doubts I guess ;)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If you are running trusted code only, this is not an issue. If you are running some untrusted code in the sandbox (e.g. Java applets in browser, J2ME, SIM cards, …), you need to consider such attacks.

Comment: @dima Dishonest devs have access to the whole codebase, there's no defense from that.

Comment: @v6ak If an applet contains business logic which decides on your entitlement to withdraw funds, then that's your problem right there. No real app does that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this is not quite true. There are different levels of security, and people generally only have access to code they need to work with. You don't think that everyone at Amazon has access to your credit card number, do you?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sure, nobody sane would do this in the applet. It is just an example of a sandboxed environment. When you are implementing Java applets, you are interacting with sandboxed code, so have to consider this problem. Well, you will not interact with bank accounts, but with something else, maybe with a filesystem. But the same rules apply.

Comment: @Dima Well, Amazon specifically has service-oriented architecture, which means that a component's security is implemented at the over-the-wire protocol level. If I write my code against some other code, and have to test it, then at least I get the class files. If some project, somewhere, does implement security between modules of the same application, then that's just an exception proving my point: these situations are very rare.

Comment: @v6ak Yes, that's a good example. Basically, the applicability is to *framework* code which must work with untrusted client code and not let it exceed its intended privileges. This is a highly specialized concern, which is just my point: it has very low applicability and general programmers should better expend their effort on improving some other aspect of their programming skill.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Agree. Programmers should at least design the code well. If the code checked permissions in a factory method and (had a private or package-private constructor), it would be a nicer design. Moreover, the partially initialized state would AFAIK  never exist when a proper factory was used.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik exceptions never prove any points. It's just a fallacy.

Comment: @dima If the point is that some event occurs very rarely, then finding an instance of the event, at the same time revealing the amount of search that was needed to find that one instance, indeed proves the point.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But simply saying "if an event exists, then it proves my point" is not it :)

Comment: @v6ak Yes, quite right. No sane design has such massive logic and checking done in an object constructor. Constructors are for lightweight objects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, one more point. Every programmer that writes multithreaded code should be aware of various pitfalls. (Deciding not to write any multithreaded code is a legal alternative.) This pitfall is not even a security-only (or sandbox-only) concern. In typical multithreaded application, there might be different way of mitigation such problems (incl. documenting some classes as non-threadsafe), though.

Comment: @v6ak Of course, thread safety is a real concern, but the need to know how to precisely exploit thread-unsafe code for nefarious purposes, and how to defend against such exploits, is mostly nonexistent. This whole subject really harks back to 1996, when Java was marketed as a platform which was supposed to have all it takes to safely execute untrusted code in an embedded JVM. Today, less than 0.1% of Java code is written to deal specifically with that concern.